# Why <a href='#'> refresh the whole page in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am learning Angular 4.0 from this [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) on its website. I can run the sample, but meet the problem in my project when I want to add a  to simulate a dropdown list using boostarp. Let's look the details:

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'mission', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'user', component: SlUserPanelComponent },
{ path: 'mission', component: SlMissionPanelComponent }
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

when type 'http ://localhost:3000' in browser, the page will redirect to 'http ://localhost:3000/mission' and show everything.

Then I add following code to the html corresponding to '/mission', and click the hyperlink, the browser will come back to 'http ://localhost:3000' and redirect to 'http ://localhost:3000/mission' again. That is not my expection, as my understand, it should not refresh the page and just show the dropdown list after click.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
        <b class="caret"></b>
        ......
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know why and how to fix the problem.

Comment: If you don't want to link anywhere, why are you using a link? Use a `<button type="button">` if you want a control that just triggers JS with no fallback.

Comment: Yes, button is good idea. I want to know why <a> can't do it since I am learning.

Comment: I use dropdown in ngx-bootstrap (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap) now, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As you are can see any angular application will have a path as

```
http://localhost:3000/#/home
```

When you are using

```
<a href="#">
```

Your path will be navigated to

```
http:localhost/3000/#/home#
```

which is a new route and angular tries to map this route to any available routes . so your app refreshes

Answer (score 0):

Following should work
 `<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">`

Comment: Thanks. I try href="javascript:;" and href="javascript:void(0);", it doesn't work and throw the error:                                                                                      Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at desc.get (zone.js:1265)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-1.10.2.js:5011)
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (jquery-1.10.2.js:5691)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.10.2.js:657)
    at init.each (jquery-1.10.2.js:266)
    at init.trigger (jquery-1.10.2.js:5690)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.g.toggle (bootstrap.min.js:6)